# Eclipse freezes on android related autocomplete

Tags: android, eclipse, autocomplete, adt, ubuntu-11.04

I've got a vanilla Eclipse, installed the ADT and started following some tutorials. Mostly it works fine. It will build the project fine, launch the emulator and run the compiled android app, I can edit the XML, and some portions of the java files, but once the autocomplete box pops up, that's it. Eclipse freezes totally. The CPU usage of eclipse drops to 0% and nothing happens. I've waited a couple of minutes, but with 0% CPU I don't see the point. And even 10 seconds wait that frequently when typing makes it unusable.

I have found [references to downloading the source](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7850#c8) and putting it into `platforms/android-X/sources` and I've done that, but the problem has not gone away. (Admittedly I've just downloaded the froyo sources and put it in `android-8` - I was hoping I wouldn't have to do it for every version of android - I also have directories for 7, 9 and 10 in `/platforms/`).

I am using Ubuntu Natty (11.04) so I guess it is possible the new window manager (Unity) might be having a problem, but I've searched http://launchpad.net and not found anything there.

I have no other plugins installed apart from ADT (and it's dependencies). The version of Eclipse is Galileo (3.5.2) from the Ubuntu Natty repositories. ADT is version 12.0.0.v201106281929-128431.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse freezes when perform auto-complete is really a bug, and it's fixed in Eclipse 3.6.2. You should upgrade to your Eclipse to latest version.

Cheers.

Comment: (Eventually) upgraded to 3.7.x and the bug no longer exists. You would have thought that autocomplete would have been debugged properly ages ago though :/ Thanks anyway

Comment: 3.7 is better, but I still get it AT LEAST once a week. I've increased my Heap size too (a recommendation I read somewhere) but it didn't make a difference. Gotta convince the boss to buy my team IntelliJIDEA 11.

Comment: I get one of these freezes every few minutes on 3.7.2 with the android sdk. Exactly 10 seconds of zero cpu usage, usually right after switching tabs. Gave it a 1gb heap out of 4gb total, and it's only using 300mb most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of bugs in eclipse, like this. You can't do anything, except upgrade to higher versions, what make other bugs, but they will be fixed later :)