# Eclipse freezes when using "ctrl+space" for Android autocomplete popup

Tags: java, android, eclipse, autocomplete

Last week I faced a problem of windows activation and my windows start slow down. After I solved that problem, windows run normally as before but I got Errors in Eclipse for developing android applications.

Everything is OK in Eclipse and I'm using "ctrl+space" in Java Projects is fine, Autocomplete popup is shown and working properly.

But, when I use "ctrl+space" in Android project, autocomplete popup show with several options and eclipse suddenly freeze for a couple of minutes(sometimes more than 3 or 4 minutes). After that I can choose the first option from the popup by hitting enter, but scroll down or choose another option, it's freeze again and wait for another several minutes.

Here is my environment.

> - Windows 7 (64bit)
> - Eclipse Juno - build id - 20120614-1722
> - ADT 22.6.0.v201403010043
> - JDK-7u51 x64

Here is Eclipse.ini file.

> -startup
>
> plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
>
> --launcher.library
>
> plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
>
> -product
>
> org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
>
> --launcher.defaultAction
>
> openFile
>
> --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
>
> 512M
>
> -showsplash
>
> org.eclipse.platform
>
> --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
>
> 256m
>
> --launcher.defaultAction
>
> openFile
>
> -startup
>
> D:\Android\Eclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
>
> --launcher.library
>
> D:\Android\Eclipse\eclipse\plugin\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
>
> -vmargs
>
> -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
>
> -Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
>
> -Xms1024m
>
> -Xmx1024m

My problem is similar to

1. [**Eclipse freezes on android related autocomplete**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774485/)
2. [**eclipse freezes when "android.R.attr" is selected from autocomplete popup**](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7850)

But I'm using the same Eclipse on my desktop and laptop. Laptop run normally on Android and working fine. The only problem is on my desktop. So, upgrading to another Eclipse is not the best option to solve (just my opinion). Because I've tried latest Eclipse (Juno), but problem still happened.

I think, some program or file is missing after I repaired windows activation which is something like [**Eclipse Juno - Constant crash when highlighting anything**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968580/). Then I update my graphic driver, testing html files, everything work like charm.But that time, I uninstalled some software from my system as *Blue Stack*, *ASUS Smart Doctor*, *Cheat Engine*, *GTalk* and *others...*(maybe 7 or 8. don't remember all).

I have no idea which program is blocking or making lag of popping up android autocomplete. I'm using only English Language and not install any other language in my computer, which is like [**Content Assist (Ctrl + Space) Is Not Working – Eclipse**](http://www.mkyong.com/java/content-assist-ctrl-space-is-not-working-eclipse/). Because I can use "ctrl+space" in java projects.

Another thing is I cannot hover or highlight on anything in every Projects. Java projects, I can use "ctrl+space" and choose any options from autocomplete popup but cannot hover on some variable, eclipse crash. Android projects, both "ctrl+space" and hover on something cannot use, eclipse hang.

Can anyone suggest me for my problem.

Comment: You can try to enlarge the Java heapspace. Maybe that's the failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally, I solved it!**

Mozila firefox was crashed (I don't know how it's happening). Chrome is my default browser and I tried html files by chrome, that reason why I don't know about crashed Mozila. After reinstalled the latest version (Mozila 29 beta) I remember all my working environments as before.

Honestly, I didn't know Android is connected with Mozila (Maybe there is a setting to change or no setting to change). Start from now, I'm gona protect and taking care of Mozila as my son.  :D

Answer (score 0):

I have had the exact same issue with my Eclipse. You can start by increasing `XXMaxPermSize`, though there is the possibility that it could make Eclipse unstable. I haven't had a problem personally, but it came up in the documentation. Usually you have to find the balance between `MaxPermSize` and the `Xms` value.

The one thing I see that should be changed right away is that your `Xms` and `Xmx` are the same. Due to the way the JVM works, they should never be set to the same value. I suggest either halving `Xms` or doubling `Xmx` and see what it does.

Another thing you can try is run it with the -clean argument. You can add it in the .ini or you can put it after the file name under "target" in your shortcut properties.

Comment: Sir, thanks for your valued suggestions. I halve down Xms to 512, MaxPermSize to 512 also. But problem still happening. Also tried -clean in Desktop shortcut, but no luck.

Comment: You may find this thread helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304312/max-value-of-xmx-and-xms-in-eclipse

Really the only thing you can do is determine what values are right for your OS, whether they be determined through trial and error or through extensive research